# Need help to check scala code can be made concise. Find all factors of n

Tags: scala, functional-programming, factors

Below implementation is to find all factors of given 'n' using scala. Can this scala code be concise ? Please note that the below code has O(sqrt(n)).

```scala
    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def helper(n: Int, current: Int, acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
      if (current > math.sqrt(n)) acc
      else if (n % current == 0) {
        val a = n / current
        val b = n / a
        helper(n, current + 1, acc :+ a :+ b)
      } else helper(n, current + 1, acc)
    }

    helper(A, 1, List.empty[Int]).sorted.toArray
```

I am not looking for the below solution because this is O(n) solution.

```scala
   def factors(n: Int): List[Int] = {
     (1 to n).filter(n % _ == 0)
   }
```

Comment: That looks concise enough to me, but you may take a look to the `unfold` method on **LazyList**.

Comment: Is this following code readable ? ```(for(i <- 1 to math.sqrt(A).toInt if A % i == 0) yield {(i, A / i)})
      .flatMap(t => List(t._1, t._2)).sorted.distinct.toArray```

Comment: Since your code works already, consider asking on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (but please take a look at their site guidelines first).

Comment: Also, instead of appending to a `List`, try prepending to it. If you don't want it in that order, you can reverse it at the end.

Comment: Sure. Thanks @user. I agree. I will post this on Code Review

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 def factors(n: Int): List[Int] = {
     (1 to n).filter(n % _ == 0)
   }
```

Is indeed O(n).

But

```
def factors(n: Int) = 
  (1 to sqrt(n).toInt).filter(n % _ == 0).flatMap { k => Seq(k, n/k) }
```

is O(sqrt(n)) :)